# How to debug WordPress "Cron" wp_schedule_event

Tags: cron

How can I debug problems with WordPress Cron? I think it will trigger when users go to your site but any errors wont be shown to them, as the jobs are run "asynchronously". So how might I debug errors?

I use [`wp schedule event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)

Comment: Use [Advanced Cron Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cron-manager/) plugin

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can run WP cron manually by calling: `http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

If you don't want the automatic cron to run while you're debugging, then add this to your `/wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

If you're on a development environment and want to output debug information, calling it manually like that will show you your debug output.

Alternatively you can use PHP's built-in [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to log message strings to the error log for debugging.  You'd need to use this in conjunction with [WP_DEBUG settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Log), as mentioned by Rarst.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the `?doing_cron` parameter.

Comment: I believe it should be `?doing_wp_cron` instead of `?doing_cron`.

Comment: @liviucmg Yes, you're right. I've made the tweak.

Comment: Is the `?doing_wp_cron` parameter required? See [EasyCron's manual set up tutorial](https://www.easycron.com/cron-job-tutorials/how-to-set-up-cron-job-for-wordpress).

Comment: @gabrielk Is the ?doing_cron parameter required? what does it mean?

Comment: How do you test a specific job? wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron={hook} doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 10):

You could debug manually, by creating an action and executing the Cron action inside. Like this:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['the_cron_test'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    error_reporting( 1 );

    do_action( 'this_is_cron_event_hook' );

    die();

} );
```

And by going to your website's address: `http://example.com?the_cron_test`

This should show you any errors with the cron task.

But it's without any sense doing it manually. You could use [Advanced Cron Manager PRO](https://www.wpart.co/downloads/advanced-cron-manager-pro/) plugin which does this for you and also saves the log and other stats.

Comment: This is the best method, as the ones outlined above (and below) do not show any output.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the plugin [Cron-View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-view/). There you can see if your job is a) registered and b) what the next due time is.

In addition, you could add a lower schedule-timer to your event (e.g. every 2 min) and test your method more frequently on a local system. Use the 'cron_schedules' filter hook to register new schedule times. For example:

```
function my_additional_schedules($schedules) {
    // interval in seconds
    $schedules['every2min'] = array('interval' => 2*60, 'display' => 'Every two minutes');
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'my_additional_schedules');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can (and probably should in any case, cron or not) [configure PHP error log](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Log) to capture all errors.