# Where in the page load code is wp-cron triggered?

Tags: wp-cron

I just spent way too much time trying to troubleshoot why my wp-cron job wasn't running. It seems, under 4.9.8, the only way to run cron is by calling the `wp-cron.php` file as a URL.

The docs say though, that it should run on page loads, though I can't locate where. Any help, please?

Comment: Do you have `DISABLE_WP_CRON` defined in wp-config?

Comment: I do not, at least not in any way I can locate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress cron is run by the `wp_cron()` function, which is hooked to run on the `init` hook, which runs on every page load.

`wp_cron()` is defined in `wp-includes/cron.php` and hooked in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

The `wp_cron()` function kicks off a `wp_remote_post()` request to `/wp-cron.php`. Some server configurations prevent scripts sending a request to the same domain like this however, so as an alternative you can set the `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` constant to `true`. When enabled this redirects the user to the current URL but with `?doing_wp_cron=` added to the URL, instead of the post request.

Comment: I'm using the official Wordpress Docker container, do you have any details on the possible server configurations that would break this?