# Posts miss schedule, no notification (3.7.1)

Tags: scheduled-posts

I have a site running 3.7.1 where posts are sporadically failing to post on schedule.

Unlike the "missed schedule" error that sometimes occurs, these misses  don't generate any notification and the posts are not flagged in any way.

In the posts that have failed to publish, reviewing the settings shows that WordPress shows that the posts are still set as "scheduled" despite having a date that is in the past.

One thing that is unique to this site, compared to other WP sites that I've managed in the past: there are over two months (60+) of posts scheduled for the future at any given time.

Other possible causes seem to be plugin related. I am running [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) on the site. I have tweaked the settings extensively and disabled the plugin but I have still seen the error, so I am skeptical there.

Has anyone else encountered an issue like this?

p.s. I am currently testing the [WP Missed Schedule Fix Failed Future Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-missed-schedule/) to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: What all have you done to debug? Does the issue still occur when using a core-bundled Theme (such as Twenty Twelve) and all Plugins disabled? Have scheduled posts always or never worked on the site? Have you verified that cron fires properly?

Comment: Thanks for your response Chip. I am still in the early debugging stage disabling one plugin at a time and testing the chron. Is there a method that you can recommend for verifying that WP's chron is firing? Posts generally publish on schedule, but every so often one misses the trigger (it works more often than not). There don't appear to be any commonalities between the missed posts.

Comment: Try the advice here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/how-to-debug-wordpress-cron-wp-schedule-event/13629#13629

Comment: Thanks again. I'll update this post as I get closer to a resolution.

Comment: @YahSureMan have you figured anything out on this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

We were never able to isolate the root cause of this but did resolve the issue using this plugin: [WP Missed Schedule Fix Failed Future Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-missed-schedule/)

Answer (score 1):

I started logging failed crons using this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cron-debug-log/) and found out that my crons are timing out causing posts to not always publish.

After seeing that it is timing out I scoured WP Trac and found an active [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8923) about this issue and it links to a related [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18738) where it looks like a patch is in the works.

To fix our problem we upped the timeout to 2 seconds by hacking the core :/

*Note: If you use the cron logging plugin and have cron disable you need to look for ra_http_WP_HTTP_curl in your options table and not ra_http_WP_Http_Streams.*