# Why cron doesn't work to me?

Tags: wp-cron

I'm on centOS 7 and I have a WordPress site. Due to some problems with the WordPress default wp-cron settings, I have chosen to do the cron tasks with my server instead. 
I have used this command:

```
wget http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

to run every 10 minutes. This works, every ten minutes it try to wget that page but it doesn't generate any outputs and the WordPress cron tasks are not executed.

Furthermore, if I try to open the page: http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1 by myself on my browser,  I get a blank page... Is this an error? I don't get any message in the Apache error log.

Comment: Having `> /dev/null 2>&1` after any command is going to not have any output.  What do you think it's supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is that with this line seems to not execute the wp-cron tasks...

Comment: I'm not following, you said you have problems with wp-cron and are using the system cron.  What are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to know why the system cron doesn't execute the wp-cron tasks when that command is executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have **`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`** set in wp-config? You need  it to have the system cron fire up the wp-cron tasks. Go to the bottom of the database settings in wp-config.php, typically around line 37, and **add it**.

**Then setup the system cron to fire up the wp-cron tasks**:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - "http://example.com/wp-cron.php?t=`date +\%s`" > /dev/null 2>&1

#Sometimes it might be required to run PHP directly:
*/5 * * * * php /home/$USER/public_html/wp-cron.php
```

`?doing_wp_cron` is appended only automatically when you define `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` as `true` in `wp-config.php`. Since you are disabling it entirely, you want to use the URL above instead or the 2nd method, which dispenses parameters.

If you're on a development environment and want to output debug information, calling it manually like that will show you your debug output.

Alternatively you can use PHP's built-in [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to log message strings to the error log for debugging.  You'd need to use this in conjunction with [WP_DEBUG settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Log).

If you need further help debugging it, try this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/how-to-debug-wordpress-cron-wp-schedule-event/13655#13655).

Answer (score -1):

For people reaching this page because they use FastCGI and they can't find a way to run `wp-cron.php`

#### Issue with FastCGI:

When using FastCGI there is an issue that prevents wp-cron.php to be run from the browser.

To fix it, comment the following lines in your `wp-cron.php`:

> Remember that it is not recommended to modify core WordPress files, so proceed only if you know what you are doing.

**Before**:

```php
/* Don't make the request block till we finish, if possible. */
if (function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request') && version_compare(phpversion(), '7.0.16', '>=')) {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header('Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    }

    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```

**After**:

```php
/* Don't make the request block till we finish, if possible. */
//if (function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request') && version_compare(phpversion(), '7.0.16', '>=')) {
//    if (!headers_sent()) {
//        header('Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT');
//        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
//    }
//
//    fastcgi_finish_request();
//}
```

Comment: 1. This actually do not answer the question
2. Never ever modify core files (should not modify plugin files and theme files as well, but there are some exceptions to the rule regarding them)

Comment: 1. It answers the question for other people landing here which use FastCGI.

Comment: 2. Unfortunately, there is no workaround other than modifying the wp-cron.php file, that I know.

Comment: 1. it needs to answer the question the OP asks, not what people think they should ask. 2 in that case there is no workaround. If it a fastcgi problem you should submit a ticket on wordpress trac.